# Can anyone explain what this code will do?

Tags: c

Can anyone tell me what this C statement means?

```
 static uint8_t chess_storage(DM%2) host_response[14] ;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not valid C, you can't have a `%` in that location. And you also can't have that entire `chess_storage(DM%2)` thing in there, unless (possibly) it's a macro that does something that you *can* do.

This:

```
static uint8_t host_response[14];
```

would declare `host_response` as an array of 14 8-bit unsigned integers (aka "bytes").

If we add this:

```
#define chess_storage(size)
#define DM 1
```

then the code becomes at least valid, substituting we get a call of the macro `chess_storage` with the argument `1%2`, which the preprocessor is able to compute. Since the macro is empty, that whole term will just go away, leaving the above array declaration.

There are probably other more "artistic" macros possible, too.

Comment: For what it's worth chess_storage() is a decorator for DSP memory allocation, using chessDE.